# Policy Enforcer configuration using Keycloak in Quarkus

Tags: java, authentication, authorization, keycloak, quarkus

I tried to run the [keycloak-authorization](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/tree/master/integration-tests/keycloak-authorization) example from the quarkus repository.
The policy enforcer config is as follows:

```
# Enable Policy Enforcement
quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.enable=true
quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.enforcement-mode=ENFORCING
-----
-----
# Disables policy enforcement for a path
quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.paths.4.path=/api/public
quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.paths.4.enforcement-mode=DISABLED
```

When I tried to access /api/public without any authorization, it is showing 401 Unauthorized error. So my question is whether this is an expected behavior? From what I have understood, since enforcement-mode is set to DISABLED, the API should be accessible by public without any authorization. I need to build some APIs which should be publicly available. How can I get this behaviour?

Also when I repeatedly access this api, I get "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request has already been read" time to time.

Comment: Is this in dev mode? If so, you're probably running into this bug: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/9565

Comment: Yes, I'm using dev mode. As of now, this problem exists only in 1.4.2 but it works fine in 1.4.1 and below.

Comment: This is for a long time ago, but I think the problem lies in some bugs in older version of Quarkus. Try newer versions to resolve the problem.